# Making a real-time multiplayer minigame

Tags: html, websocket

I have a very simple concept of minigame that I want to be playable by up to four players at once. It will be played on an HTML5 canvas, and I already have it working in single-player with three CPU-controlled "players".

The game itself is simple, it just relies on timing and pushing your button as the arrow points towards it. In theory I could just have the game focus on the user's own button, and then just show how everyone did at the end, but what I'd really like to do is for the arrow to move faster the better people are doing - this will essentially allow the difficulty of the game to adjust itself.

So I'm thinking I need to use WebSockets. Only trouble is, I've never used them before and I can't find a single resource that isn't insanely confusing.

By my understanding, I just need the client to send a message to the server when the player pushes their button, and on receipt of that message the server can compute how accurate the player was, and adjust the speed accordingly, passing on that result to the other players.

I'm just worried about what effect lag could have on this setup. What if the arrow reaches the next player before their browser has received the message from the server informing them of how the last player did (and therefore what speed the arrow is going at)?

Am I just being too ambitious with this? Should I just stick with the idea of having four individual games whose total scores are tallied together?

Comment: Just had a thought that may help. If lag may be too much of an issue, I could make the game playable only by people on the same IP, thus encouraging friends to play together. Is it possible to connect browsers to each other to play, or do WebSockets only work with client-server setups?

Comment: Do some research on lock-step networking. It's fairly straight forward to implement but not overly versatile. You can experiment with more complex client-server setups afterwards.